# dbstart won't accept $ORACLE_HOME

Tags: oracle, rhel

I'm trying to start some oracle databases on RHEL, however when I run the `dbstart` command, I get an error message saying `ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER` isn't set.

```
[oracle@olxxxa ~]$ dbstart $ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER is not SET, unable to auto-start Oracle Net Listener
Usage: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbstart ORACLE_HOME
Processing Database instance "xxxa": log file /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/startup.log
Processing Database instance "xxxb": log file /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/startup.log
```

Looking online, I saw people were saying to change the dbstart file so that ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER is set from $1 to $ORACLE_HOME, which I did however I'm still getting the same error. I also read that I could pass $ORACLE_HOME right into the dbstart command, however I get the same output with or without the variable being passed.

Comment: Is `ORACLE_HOME` actually set? What happens if you do `dbstart /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1` instead of passing the variable?

Comment: I get the same output when running it that way. when I run `echo $ORACLE_HOME`, I get a blank response, so is that saying the variable isn't set? where/how can I set it?

Comment: I'm surprised passing the actual path on the command line doesn't work, even if the variable isn't set. If you run `. oraenv <SID>` it should set everything up with the right home and path.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I ran the `echo $ORACLE_HOME` as the oracle user and not as root. I gave it a ran as root and it came back good. I ran `dbstart` as root (which I was told _not_ to do as it would give me issues later on) and it ran without issue, however it didn't solve the other problem I was having (a network issue when connecting to xxxa). 

running the `. oraenv` I'm not exactly sure what its asking. from what I see online, its not clear what I should put in, so I just put (what I think is) the home directory `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1` for both the SID and HOME.